# Why do C# Records produce a different Linq Expression when an implicit conversion is implemented?

Tags: c#, .net-core, type-conversion

I'd like to understand why a C# Record with an implicit conversion generates an unexpected Linq Expression.

The following link provides a demo of how different Linq Expressions are generated for a Record when it has the same implicit conversion implementation as a Class or Struct.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LDJJct

This was discovered while developing a custom type to use with Entity Framework. Entity Framework threw an error stating that the expression was not supported when the custom type was implemented using a Record. The expression behaves as expected when using a Class or Struct.

This led us to discover that the root issue appears to be that the generated .NET Expression was different for the Record implementation.

Expression using Record or Record Struct (Unexpected):

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (Convert(x.Id, Record) == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._record))
```

Expression using Class or Struct (Expected):

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (x.Id == Convert(value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._class, Int32)))
```

The `Convert(x.Id, Record)` is ultimately what was not expected and not supported by default with Entity Framework. I'm aware that EF ValueConverters can address this. But I wanted to know why this produces a different expression.

Interestingly, if you comment out one of the operators on a Record then you get the expected Linq Expression with the Record!

**UPDATE** - To clarify, I'm particularly interested in whether Records can be coerced into generating an Expression which more resembles the ones generated for the Class and Struct examples. And mostly I'd like to understand why Records have this unexpected behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Tornhoof, Records have some built-in comparisons and it was influencing the approach the compiler was taking to achieve the conversion and ultimately the comparison.

In short, also adding == and != operators on the Record resulted in the valid Expression that was originally expected.

```
public record Record(int Id)
{
    public static bool operator ==(Record a, int b)
    {
        return a.Id == b;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(int a, Record b)
    {
        return a != b.Id;
    }
    
    public static bool operator !=(Record a, int b)
    {
        return a.Id == b;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(int a, Record b)
    {
        return a != b.Id;
    }   
    
    public static implicit operator int(Record hashId) => hashId.Id;

    public static implicit operator Record(int id) => new Record(id);
}
```

This now produced

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (x.Id == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._record))
```

For those also dabbling in this because you want a strongly typed ID, I recommend checking out this library.

https://github.com/andrewlock/StronglyTypedId

Answer (score 1):

From the [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1145-binary-operator-overload-resolution);

> If the set of candidate user-defined operators is not empty, then this becomes the set of candidate operators for the operation. Otherwise, the predefined binary operator «op» implementations, including their lifted forms, become the set of candidate operators for the operation.

In other words, because the C# compiler defines the "user-defined" `==` operator for all record types. And because you have an implicit cast from `int`, this operator is a candidate.

So the "predefined" `bool operator ==(int x, int y)` is not considered at all, even though the record argument has an implicit conversion to that type.

You can either define more "user-defined" equality operators, remove your `record(int)` implicit conversion, or add an explicit cast in every expression.

Comment: Ah, ok! That does explain why Records are special in this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Records implement a lot of defaults for you. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

If you do that manually on your struct:

```cs
public struct Struct : IEquatable<Struct>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Struct(int Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public static implicit operator int (Struct hashId) => hashId.Id;
    public static implicit operator Struct(int id) => new Struct(id);
    public static bool operator !=(Struct a, Struct b) => !Equals(a, b);
    public static bool operator ==(Struct a, Struct b) => Equals(a, b);
    public bool Equals(Struct s)
    {
        return this.Id == s.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Id;
    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (o is Struct s)
        {
            return Equals(this, s);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

then it becomes:

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (Convert(x.Id, Record) == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._record))
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (Convert(x.Id, RecordStruct) == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._recordStruct))
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (x.Id == Convert(value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._recordWithoutOperator, Int32)))
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (Convert(x.Id, Struct) == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._struct))
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestObject].Where(x => (x.Id == Convert(value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0)._class, Int32)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! What I'm looking for is the opposite though. I was curious how the Record's Expression could be made to look like the others. i.e. I don't want the "(Convert(x.Id, Record)" version.